# ros.pde compile error BYTE not declared in this scope

Tags: ros, arduino, arbotix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with latest Fuerte install and arduino 0023
I have followed all the instructions on the websites, but when I try to compile the ros.pde sketch I get the following errors.
Any help would be appreciated.
-Scott

ros.cpp: In function ‘int handleRead()’:
ros.cpp:238:21: error: ‘BYTE’ was not declared in this scope
ros.cpp: In function ‘void statusPacket(int, int)’:
ros.cpp:266:21: error: ‘BYTE’ was not declared in this scope
ros.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’:
ros.cpp:325:33: error: ‘BYTE’ was not declared in this scope
ros.cpp:472:31: error: ‘BYTE’ was not declared in this scope
ros.cpp:513:48: error: ‘BYTE’ was not declared in this scope

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38761/ros.pde-compile-error-byte-not-declared-in-this-scope/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I found the fix from a related posting on a sparkfun site, apparently BYTE has been deprecated in the Serial package
http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=30991

Thus

```
Serial.print(value, BYTE);
```

need to be replaced with:

```
 Serial.write(value);

So to fix this, edit the ros.pde file and remove all BYTE entries, (after backing it up first) then save it and it compiles perfectly!
-Scott
```

---

Originally posted by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) with karma: 693 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-07-14**:
I believe this has already been fixed in trunk, the Arduino-1.0 compatible releases will be out shortly, and so this won't be an issue.

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2012-10-03**:
Fergs. Is this fix now incl in the recent Oct 1/12 release of arbotix-0015.zip, that includes what appears to be a new Biolod pypose.ino file? Further: Rereading the Arbotix Package arbotix_firmware wiki & locating the Vanadium-ros-pkg Source, discovered a Mar 21/12 ros.ino. It compiles & loads

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-10-14**:
Yes, arbotix-0015 + the ros.ino in vanadium-ros-pkg should work fine with arduino 1.0+.